# How to make RadioButton text invisible but the button itself to stay visible(Xamarin.Android)?

Tags: text, invisible, android-radiobutton

Is there a way to hide the text of a RadioButton but the button itself(the circle) to stay visible?

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just set the android:text= to ""

Comment: I want every `RadioButton` to have value but to be hidden from the user.

Comment: Not sure you can hide the text unless you use a separate control. Could you set the text colour on a binding style property and hide it that way?

Comment: Yes that is an option.